# c# Wrapper for CNTK step 2

Tags: c#, cntk

This is a follow-up question from "c# Wrapper for CNTK step"
After adding  reference EvalWrapper.dll,  The type or namespace name 'IEvaluateModelManagedF' could not be found error went away.

The next compile error I encounter is at line

```
model.CreateNetwork(string.Format("deviceId=-1\nmodelPath=\"{0}\"", modelFilePath));
```

> Error CS1061  'IEvaluateModelManagedF' does not contain a definition for 'CreateNetwork' and no extension method 'CreateNetwork' accepting a first argument of type 'IEvaluateModelManagedF' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I made sure all the DLLs are in the same directory as EvalWrapper.dll. 
What am I missing ? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Everything up to the offending line?

Comment: Thanks for helping. The source code is the original code from  source code CNTK program.cs .  The comment doesn't allow me to put the complete code here.
        private static void EvaluateModelSingleLayer()
        {
        ....
        .....
                    // Load model
                    string modelFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\Output\Models\01_OneHidden");                    model.CreateNetwork(string.Format("deviceId=-1\nmodelPath=\"{0}\"", modelFilePath));

Comment: Can't repro with the information you post here. I just created an empty C# project, referenced `EvalWrapper.dll` (from a directory where all other required DLLs are present), adding a `using`, and then the code bits from `EvaluateModelSingleLayer` compiled just fine. Terry, you can edit your original question and add relevant code snippets. What type of project did you create? I could only imagine that your project is targeting a wrong architecture or something funny like that, that would prevent it from successfully loading the `EvalWrapper`

Comment: Thanks again. What is the "using"   need to add?  I will try it on another machine if this still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this error too. To solve the problem you should add the following `using` clause at the beginning of your code:

```
using Microsoft.MSR.CNTK.Extensibility.Managed;
```